# Theano: cublasSgemm failed (14) an internal operation failed

Tags: cuda, theano, cublas

Sometimes, after a while of running fine, I get such an error with Theano / CUDA:

```
RuntimeError: cublasSgemm failed (14) an internal operation failed
 unit=0 N=0, c.dims=[512 2048], a.dim=[512 493], alpha=%f, beta=%f, a=%p, b=%p, c=%p sa_0=%d, sa_1=%d, sb_0=%d, sb_1=%d, sc_0=%d, sc_1=%d
Apply node that caused the error: GpuDot22(GpuReshape{2}.0, GpuReshape{2}.0)
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix), CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(512, 493), (493, 2048)]
Inputs strides: [(493, 1), (2048, 1)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
```

As my code runs fine for a while (I do Neural Network training, and it runs most of the time through, and even when this error occurred, it already ran fine for >2000 mini-batches), I wonder about the cause of this. Maybe some hardware fault?

This is with CUDA 6.0 and a very recent Theano (yesterday from Git), Ubuntu 12.04, GTX 580.

I also got the error with CUDA 6.5 on a K20:

```
RuntimeError: cublasSgemm failed (14) an internal operation failed
 unit=0 N=0, c.dims=[2899 2000], a.dim=[2899 493], alpha=%f, beta=%f, a=%p, b=%p, c=%p sa_0=%d, sa_1=%d, sb_0=%d, sb_1=%d, sc_0=%d, sc_1=%d
Apply node that caused the error: GpuDot22(GpuReshape{2}.0, GpuReshape{2}.0)
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix), CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(2899, 493), (493, 2000)]
Inputs strides: [(493, 1), (2000, 1)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
```

(Another error I sometimes got in the past is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221191/theano-cuda-error-an-illegal-memory-access-was-encountered) now instead. Not sure if this is related.)

Via [Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4580205/markus), who got the same error:

```
RuntimeError: cublasSgemm failed (14) an internal operation failed
 unit=0 N=0, c.dims=[2 100], a.dim=[2 9919], alpha=%f, beta=%f, a=%p, b=%p, c=%p sa_0=%d, sa_1=%d, sb_0=%d, sb_1=%d, sc_0=%d, sc_1=%d
Apply node that caused the error: GpuDot22(GpuFlatten{2}.0, weight_hidden_)
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix), CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(2, 9919), (9919, 100)]
Inputs strides: [(9919, 1), (100, 1)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
```

With CUDA 6.5, Windows 8.1, Python 2.7, GTX 970M.

> The error only occurs in my own network, if I run the LeNet example from Theano, it runs fine. Though the network is compiling and running fine on the CPU (and also on the GPU for some colleagues using Linux). Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: What OS? What GPU? Is your GPU used as a display device as well?

Comment: @MichalHosala: Ubuntu 12.04, I think GTX 580 (not sure - I already deleted the log). It's used exclusively by that process.

Comment: I am reasonably sure that error code typically indicates the kernel inside the call timed out. Since the run-time of SGEMM is roughly proportional to the product of the dimensions n*m*k, your matrices may be too big. But if I interpret your data above correctly, the matrices don't seem all that large and a GTX 580 is fairly fast. But maybe your app creates larger intermediate matrices under the hood? I would suggest examining kernel run times with the profiler. Also, try a GPU that is not used for the GUI but is operated as a compute-only device.

Comment: @njuffa: In case of a timeout, could I maybe just increase the timeout, or disable it completely? (Why is it there at all?) And I already use the GPU exclusively for computation.

Comment: @Albert: A GPU can either run a compute kernel or service the operating system's GUI. All operating systems supported by CUDA have a watchdog timer to prevent the GUI freezing for indefinite periods of time and will kill a CUDA kernel that exceeds the time limit (typically a couple of seconds). On Windows, I think all GPUs running under WDDM control are subject to the watchdog, on Linux it happens if you run X on the GPU. Yes, you can change the timeout limit, it is OS specific and I do not have the details at hand. Time-out is just a working hypothesis at this point.

Comment: @njuffa: There is no X server running on the GPU. It's in exclusive mode and just my process uses it.

Comment: @Albert:  I do not have any other hypotheses at this time, you might want to try running in the debugger to figure out what is going on under the hood in Theano. The issue may originate up-stream of the SGEMM call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference in case anyone stumbles upon this:

This doesn't occur anymore for me. I'm not exactly sure what fixed it, but I think the main difference is that I avoid any multithreading and forks (without exec). This caused many similar problems, e.g. [Theano CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221191/theano-cuda-error-an-illegal-memory-access-was-encountered), and [Theano CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered (Google Groups discussion)](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/theano-users/Pu4YKlZKwm4/discussion). Esp. that discussion on Google Groups is very helpful.

Theano functions are not multithreading safe. However, that is not a
problem for me because I'm only using it in one thread. However, I
still think that other threads might cause these problems. Maybe it is
related to the GC of Python which frees some Cuda_Ndarray in some
other thread while the theano.function is running.

I looked a bit at the [relevant Theano code](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/sandbox/cuda/cuda_ndarray.cu) and not sure if it covers
all such cases.

Note that you might even not be aware that you have some background
threads. Some Python stdlib code can spawn such background threads.
E.g. multiprocessing.Queue will do that.

I cannot avoid having multiple
threads, and until this is fixed in Theano, I create a new subprocess
with a single thread where I do all the Theano work. This also has
several advantages such as: More clear separation of the code, being
faster in some cases because it all really runs in parallel, and being
able to use multiple GPUs.

Note that just using the multiprocessing module did not work for me
that well because there are a few libs (Numpy and others, and maybe
Theano itself) which might behave bad in a forked process (depending
on the versions, the OS and race conditions). Thus, I needed a real
subprocess (fork + exec, not just fork).

My code is [here](https://gist.github.com/albertz/4177e40d41cb7f9f7c68), in case anyone is interested in this.

There is ExecingProcess which is modeled after multiprocessing.Process
but does a fork+exec. (Btw, on Windows, the multiprocessing module
will anyway do this, because there is no fork on Windows.)
And there is AsyncTask which adds up a duplex pipe to this which works
with both ExecingProcess and the standard multiprocessing.Process.

See also: [Theano Wiki: Using multiple GPUs](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Using-Multiple-GPUs)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue, and fwiw, in my case it was solved by eliminating the import of another library that used pycuda. It appears theano really does not like to share.